# Pygtk: Name is not defined

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm trying out a few pygtk tutorials and have run across a seemingly obvious newbie mistake, but for the life of me can't figure out what's going on here.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in 
    class Base:
  File "main.py", line 61, in Base
    cv.set_line_width(9)
NameError: name 'cv' is not defined
```

The code:

```
def expose(self, widget, data=None):  
    cv = widget.window.cairo_create()      
    cv.set_line_width(9)
    cv.set_source_rgb(0.7, 0.2, 0.0)

    w = self.window.allocation.width
    h = self.window.allocation.height

    cv.translate(w/2, h/2)
    cv.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, 2*math.pi)
    cv.stroke_preserve()

    cv.set_source_rgb(0.3, 0.4, 0.6)
    cv.fill()
```

Here is the full source: http://gist.github.com/655728

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["NameError: name 'self' is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12021511/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mixture of tabs and spaces in your file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in github reads:

```
def expose(self, widget, data=None):        
    selcv = widget.window.cairo_create()

    cv.set_line_width(9)
    cv.set_source_rgb(0.7, 0.2, 0.0)
```

...which would surely explain why cv is not defined when you try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by switching to 4-space indents instead of tabs and re-indenting the entire file.

Something weird was going on, gedit was showing everything nicely indented while Netbeans showed the indent culprit

Comment: Welcome to SO. Am glad that things worked out for you. By the way, you're entitled to tick your own question, saying that you've accepted the answer. That lets people know that they don't need to worry about providing further thought.